# systemd script do not set correct file permissions at boot time

Tags: bash, systemd, file-permissions

I have written a simple service that calls a bash script that should change file permissions at boot time. The issue is that it seems that the service is not working as the permissions are not changed by the time the user logs in.

However, when I run the service manually - `sudo systemctl start setpermissions.service` it works and the file permissions are set correctly.

This are the file permissions before the service runs:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Oct 25 09:04 /sys/module/8723cs/parameters/rtw_scan_interval_thr
```

when I run it manually (i.e. desired file permissions):

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 4096 Oct 25 09:10 /sys/module/8723cs/parameters/rtw_scan_interval_thr
```

setpermissions.service

```
[Unit]
Description="Set file permissions"

User=root

[Service]
StandardOutput=journal
ExecStart=/bin/sh /usr/bin/setpermissions.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What am I missing here? Have I configured my service incorrectly?

Note/Context: the whole goal of this service is that the user do not get prompted for root password when they attempt to write to `sys/module/8723cs/parameters/rtw_scan_interval_thr`

Answer (score 0):

The command `sudo systemctl start setpermissions.service` starts the service immediately in the current session.

To enable a service at boot, you need to run the following command:

```
sudo systemctl enable setpermissions.service
```

You can also enable and start the service in one command:

```
 sudo systemctl enable --now setpermissions.service
```